# android softkeyboard on keypress listener

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, onkeypress

A newbie on Android. Need an example of how can i use soft keyboard. What i want to achieve is on `Button` click a keyboard should appear and a `TextView` should be populated with every keypress event with the key pressed. When i try to do so i get `NullPointerException`. I couldn't understand what exactly the reason could be. Some place i read to initialize my view with `onkeylistener`, but i couldn't get where and how to do it. Please explain me the steps to implement it. Would be very helpful.

Comment: Post your code whatever you have done with logcat.